# How to pivot rows into a single comma separated string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, string-aggregation

**Important update:**

> When I try to use the suggested `string_agg` method I get this error - Specified types
> or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

**Original question**

I have a query but I'm struggling to "pivot" multiple rows into a single column of strings.

I have a `member` and a `category` table and each member can have multiple categories (this is a simplification of the scenario).

So I need to write a query to display what categories each member has, so each member has multiple categories.  When I was working in the Microsoft world I was able to use pivot but now in Postgres I'm not able to find an equivalent method.

I've seen references to crosstab and a few other methods but when trying I get errors saying the function isn't recognised.

**My attempt!**

```
select                              
    m.member_id,                                
    array.join(c.category, ",") -- this is more like a programming approach but I need something similar to this
from member m
from join category c ON c.member_id = m.id
group by 1
```

**Example with dataset**

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8ea4998f75f7db83d2360ff01bf02c82
```

I'm using Navicat Premium as my "editor"

**A second attempt**

```
select b.member_id, string_agg(distinct c.name, ',') 
from bookings b 
join category c on c.member_id = b.member_id 
group by 1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and desired results. What don't you like about your current query?

Comment: Are you looking for `string_agg(c.category, ",")`?

Comment: I've updated my question with your suggestion and I think it works actually?  I've also added distinct inside the string_agg function - I assume this is correct?

Comment: When I run this I get this error which is worrying - Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.  We use postgres but the data is lifted into aws redshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift doesn't support string_agg() function but has the listagg() function which I believe is equivalent.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

Listagg() support DISTINCT and even has a window function form.  Does this not produce your desired results?

```
select b.member_id, listagg(distinct c.name, ',') 
from bookings b 
join category c on c.member_id = b.member_id 
group by 1;
```

As for the error message in the update, that is Redshift's cryptic way to say that you have attempted to perform a leader node only operation on a compute node (or something of that ilk).  I don't see why you would get that unless string_agg() is supported as a leader only operation (generate_series() is an example of a function only supported on the leader node).

Comment: thanks!  I need to go away now and learn/ understand how postgres and redshift are working together - another thing on my list to grasp - it never ends..!